# How to serve content returned from different functions of a controller without redirection

Tags: angularjs

I have a navigation bar with options like Add/Show.

Now, I need different function of same controller be called on click of these and render results without changing the link.

For example:

When the user clicks show, the list should show up that is returned by show function of controller.

When user clicks Add, a form should show up, on submit button of which the controller function would be called.

CONTROLLER:

```
 angular.module('Todo', ['ngRoute'])
 .config(['$resourceProvider', function($resourceProvider) {
  // Don't strip trailing slashes from calculated URLs
  $resourceProvider.defaults.stripTrailingSlashes = false;
}]);


 .controller('mainController', function($scope, $http)
 {
    $scope.formData = {};
   $scope.howToDo = function() {
    // get all and show them
    $http.get('/musicians')
      .success(function(data) {
            //$scope.showList="true";
            $scope.todos = data;
            console.log(data);
        })
        .error(function(data) {
            console.log('Error: ' + data);
        });
   }

        //get with an id
        $scope.getOneTodo = function() {
        $http.get('/musicians/' + id)
            .success(function(data) {
                //$scope.showMusician="true";
                $scope.todos = data;
                      console.log(data);
            })
            .error(function(data) {
                console.log('Error: ' + data);
            });
    };
      // send the text to the node API
    $scope.createTodo = function() {
        $http.post('/musicians', $scope.formData)
            .success(function(data) {
                //$scope.showcreate ="true"
                $scope.formData = {}; // clear the form 
                $scope.todos = data;
                console.log(data);
            })
            .error(function(data) {
                console.log('Error: ' + data);
            });
    };

    // delete 
  $scope.deleteTodo = function(id) {
        $http.delete('/musicians/' + id)
            .success(function(data) {
                $scope.todos = data;
                console.log(data);
            })
            .error(function(data) {
                console.log('Error: ' + data);
            });
    };

    /*
    $scope.updateTodo = function(id) {
        $http.delete('/musicians' + id)
            .success(function(data) {
                $scope.todos = data;
                      console.log(data);
            })
            .error(function(data) {
                console.log('Error: ' + data);
            });
    };*/

});
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html ng-app="Todo">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>DemoAPI</title>

   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"><!-- Optimize mobile viewport -->
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script><!-- load jquery -->
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.8/angular.min.js"></script><!-- load angular -->
    <script src="core.js"></script>

<!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="./Client/css/styling.css" />-->
<!--<script type="text/javascript" src="/Client/public/core.js"></script>-->




</head>
 <body>
<div ng-controller="mainController">
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">
      Demp<strong>API</strong></a>
  </div>

  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li><a href="#" ng-click="showToDo()"><strong>Show Musicians</strong></a></li>
     <li><a href="#" ng-click="createTodo()"><strong>Add Musicians</strong></a></li>
  </ul>


</div>  
<form name="userForm" ng-submit="createTodo()" ng-if="" novalidate>
   <div class="row col-lg-offset-3">
      <div class="form-group col-lg-6"  ng-class="{ 'has-error': userForm.name.$invalid && userForm.name.$dirty}" >
        <label class="control-label">Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" ng-model="user.name" ng-required="true" ng-minlength="3" placeholder="Name" />
        <span class="error-message" ng-show="userForm.name.$dirty
        && userForm.name.$error.required">You are required to provide your name</span>

        <span class="error-message" ng-show="userForm.name.$dirty
        && userForm.name.$error.minlength">Your name should contain 3 or more characters</span>
      </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row col-lg-offset-3">
      <div class="form-group col-lg-6" ng-class="{ 'has-error': userForm.band.$invalid && userForm.band.$dirty }" >
        <label class="control-label">Band</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" ng-model="user.band" ng-required="true" placeholder="Your Band Name" />
        <span class="error-message" ng-show="userForm.email.$dirty
        && userForm.name.$error.required">You are required to provide your Band name </span>
      </div>
      </div>


       <div class="row col-lg-offset-3">
      <div class="form-group col-lg-6" ng-class="{ 'has-error': userForm.instrument.$invalid && userForm.instrument.$dirty }" >
        <label class="control-label">Instrument</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="instrument" ng-model="user.instrument" ng-required="true" placeholder="The Instrument you play" />
        <span class="error-message" ng-show="userForm.instrument.$dirty
        && userForm.name.$error.required">You are required the instrument you play </span>
      </div>
      </div>


  <div class="row col-lg-offset-3">
      <button class="btn btn-primary"
      ng-disabled="userForm.$invalid"
      type="submit">Save</button>

      </div>

</form>   

    </div>  




</body>
</html>
```

Can I please get some direction on this?

Comment: Sounds like a pretty basic [ng-show](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow) / [ng-click](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClick) use case but hard to say without any code.

Comment: share code and what exactly is not working or what you want

Comment: @Fissio: Updated with code.

Comment: @entre:Updated with code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a simple plunker based on your code that demonstrates a way of showing different HTML depending on controller state. I commented out some of your code since I don't have access to your server end, but the principle is the same in any case. http://plnkr.co/edit/Dvnic9b33vJpSaQeeWrA?p=preview

The important parts here are

- `$scope.navMode = undefined`, which initializes a "state" for your template (could also start by setting a value)
- `ng-show="navMode == 'createMusician'"` and `ng-show="navMode == 'showMusicians'"`, which show and hide themselves based on the value of the `navMode` variable
- `ng-click="navMode = 'showMusicians'"` and `ng-click="navMode = 'createMusician'"` in the respective navbar buttons, which change the value of the $scope variable and as such cause the different views to be shown.

You could expand further by using [ng-include](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude) to have the html for different views in separate files in case your html file gets too bloated. But this should suffice for something as small as this :)